# Wordpress LaTeX symbol inline fails

Tags: latex

I've got a problem with LaTeX and Wordpress. I want to put my formula inline with the rest of the text. I've tried several solutions, but none of them worked. I'm using Easy WP LaTeX plugin. Here's the formula:

```
blablabla $$A = \left \{ a_{1}, ..., a_{n} \right \}!$$ blablablabla...
```

I've tried this one, too:

```
blablabla $$\inline A = \left \{ a_{1}, ..., a_{n} \right \}$$ blablablabla...
```

But it's still in another line alone. What can be the problem?

Comment: You would need `$$A = \left\{ a_{1}, ..., a_{n} \right\}!$$`

Comment: It doesn't work. The ! symbol disappears, and this is all i see:blablabla $$A = \left\{ a_{1}, ..., a_{n} \right\}$$ blabla. So it's displayed as a text without the !

Comment: Put the `!` *outside* the math expression then. It doesn't seem like you're referring to factorial notation. I'm not that familiar with MathJax to know all the ins-and-outs.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to display math content together with inline text, use

```
...some text [math]A = \left\{ a_{1}, ..., a_{n} \right\}[/math]! some more text...
```

The reason why `!` should be excluded from the math content - in that particular spot - is because it is an active character within the plugin. If a math expression *starts* with `!`, it turns it into a display equation. If it *ends* with `!`, it suppresses the formula output.

See the [Easy WP LaTeX](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/easy-wp-latex-lite/) [Screenshots page](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/easy-wp-latex-lite/screenshots/):

[image]